# How to move a button to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) wheree when user clicks on the plus button, it displays a modal window.

Problem is that I want the close button to appear on the right hand side of the window, on the same line as the "PREVIOUS QUESTIONS" heading. But it doesn't seem to be moving to the right at all. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="previouslink">
<h1>PREVIOUS QUESTIONS</h1>

<button type="button" id="close" onclick="return closewindow();">Close</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#close{
    float:right;
    display:block;
    margin-right:0px;
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: It's not on the same line, @cdhowie!

Comment: By the way: `display: block` is applied by default by every browser when you add the `float`-property with a `left` or `right` value. You don't need to write it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in your `QandATableStyle2.css` file.
Remove `;` after:

```
.previouslink{
display:none;   
};
```

And it should work fine. `;` character prevents `#close` definition from loading.

Comment: That does not answer the question, but yes, that's a mistake in the CSS-file.

Comment: It answers the question. `;` prevents #close definition from loading.

Comment: Even when this mistake is corrected, `#close` won't be in the *desired* place. It will be *below* the `h1`.

Comment: Well, let's say it answers part of the question

Comment: if you want it above the h1, then put it first or float the h1 left

Answer (score 5):

As H1 is a block-element it takes all the width of the line on which it stands.
This means that the elements that follow the H1-element cannot be on the same line, even if a `float`-property is applied to it.

You could either add

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

to the `#close` element. Or add a negative margin for this element. Apart from that it's also possible to add a `float: left;` to the H1-element. Please be aware that this might cause certain problems with floating and line-breaks.

It is also possible to add the `#close`-element **before** the H1. This will prevent the H1 from taking up all space in it's line, but will recognize the close-element with its space.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted. The `position: absolute` approach is the best choice here.

Comment: Thanks, @thirtydot! I think some people think `position: absolute` is bad in all cases because they are not aware of the greatness that lies in it.

Comment: It does explain an alternative way to move the button, but it fails to explain why the current method is not working.

Comment: Well, the first line explains what the H1 does. So this explains it I think. I'll add some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `display: inline;` to the `<h1>` element, which would allow the `<button>` (also inline) to be rendered on the same line.

Note that you will likely need to style the following element to `clear: both;` if you don't want the following content bleeding into the space between the header and the button.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcyDz/5/).